# Pass data between controller methods in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using spring MVC to call restful web services, I have to pass one service data to other service like bellow please let me know best & secure way to pass date.

```
Code Example:

@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getToken() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject(new VerifyIdentityBean());
    model.setViewName("verifyIdentity");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getTokenPost() {
       **// Here I will call one web service by passing form input
      // I need to pass that service repose to next form post method**
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("redirect:/userinfo");
        return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getuser() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject(new UserBean());
    model.setViewName("userinfo");
    return model;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/userinfo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView getUserPost() {
       **//Here I want first post method service response to pass input to next web service
       // Here I will call one web service by passing above input**
    return model;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it's necessary to invoke web method by `model.setViewName("redirect:/userinfo");`. Because they are in the same service, why don't you call it directly.

```
@AutoWired
CustomService service;

@RequestMapping(value = "/verify", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView getTokenPost() {
    ModelAndView model = service.getUserPost();
    // do some modify.
    return model;
```

}

We usually define restful api in an interface, even though you don't need an interface. We usually implemant web service in another service layer. This has two benifits:
1. Decouple from controller and service.
2. The service is reusable. Like the code above.

Comment: thank you for giving reply, I am also calling web services in service layer only but my requirement is I want to retain first service response data in 2nd from post method as i need to pass as input to 2nd web service.